# Include changeable text with html code

Tags: html, wordpress, file, text

i am building a website with wordpress at the moment and would like to make it as customizable as possible. Thats why i want the client to change the text just by editing a text file on his FTP server. So basically just how you embed a picture with html, i want to embed a text file. Is it possible? Or are there other ways to realize it? Thank you so much...

Comment: You can do that with templates with Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/ but I have never done it with WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is not a great idea, why i tell this, wordpress has each own Editor which is realy easy for user to write his content.

He can upload any image or video, or whatever he wants.

I think in the way you want to do that with .txt files , it will be much difficult for the  user, but it depends to you !

The idea to show content from txt file is something like that , you can make a custom field so user update the .txt file on each wordpress page.

Then

```
<?php
$file = "the field of txt"; // the name of the custom field.
echo file_get_contents( $file ); // get the contents, and echo it out.
?>
```

Good Luck!